# Override Electron Notification Popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications, electron

I have an electron app with only a browserwindow and a URL of an webapp we are using internally. I want to override the Notification Window. Is there any tip you can give me on doing so?

I tried the following, which should make clear what I want to do:

**renderer.js** (loaded with preload)

```
const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

window.Notification.onshow = function (ev) {
    ipc.send("notification-show", ev);
};
```

**index.js**

```
const ipc = require('electron').ipcMain;

ipc.on('notification-show', function (event, arg) {
    // tray.setImage(__dirname + "/images/favicon-notification.ico");
    var notification = new VcpNotification(arg.title, arg.text);
    notification.show();
});
```

Comment: The Notification object has a `show` event and a `close()` method. https://electronjs.org/docs/api/notification ... I haven't tried this so I'm not sure whether you would hook using `app.on()` or `window.on()` or something else. But yes with the caveat that your code is pseudocode, you should be able to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, its fairly easy.

In your renderer.js do the following:

```
var Notification = function(title,ops) {
    ipc.send("notification-show", {title: title, options: ops});
};
Notification.requestPermission = () => {};
Notification.permission = "granted";
window.Notification = Notification;
```

This will override the Notification object and you can catch it wherever you want within the IPC channel "notification-show".